# Make it more clear whether a post is a question or an answer when reviewing edits

Tags: feature-request, review, suggested-edits

I have had several times where I was processing the edit review queue, for which it was very confusing to determine whether the post under review was a question or an answer. This can be a problem, because sometimes the types of edits acceptable on questions can be different from those acceptable on answers.

My current solution for those ambiguous cases is to examine the post's link, but this is slightly inconvenient and a little irritating.

Could something be added to the dialog that makes it more obvious whether the edit is to a question or an answer?